# Countable chain condition in topology

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology

A topological space $X$ is said to have the **countable chain condition (ccc)** if every collection of open and disjoint subsets of $X$ is at most countable. This definition can be found in [L. Steen, J. Seebach: Counterexamples in Topology. p.22](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-6290-9).

I am looking for a book or an article that contain the well known properties about topological spaces:

- Separability of $X$ implies that $X$ is ccc.
- For a metrizable space $X$, the ccc property implies separability.
- A counterexample of a completely regular Hausdorff space that has the ccc property but is not separable. (The website topology.pi-base.org does offer an example of such an example, namely the [Peng-Wu group](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000179). I could not find a counterexample in the Literature. Unfortunately the counterexample provided by Steen and Seebach is not completely regular.)

Comment: Problem N on page 60 of J. L. Kelley, *General Topology*, has a hint.

Comment: See the Ryszard Engelking's classic monograph on General Topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Spearable implies ccc is theorem [T21](https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000021/references) of pi-Base, which references *Counterexamples*.  The book doesn't provide a proof, but the result is standard. (Take a collection of pairwise disjoint open sets, if the space is separable then each contains a distinct point from the countable dense set, thus the collection is countable.)
- [This pi-Base search](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Countable%20chain%20condition%2BMetrizable%2B%7ESeparable) maps out a proof that metrizable and ccc implies separable. The meat of this is theorem [T62](https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000062), showing every weakly Lindelof metrizable space is second-countable, based upon the [Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology](https://doi.org/10.1016/c2009-0-12309-7).  See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4743591/.
- Once https://github.com/pi-base/data/pull/483 is reviewed and merged, @KP's suggestion from *Counterexamples* will be discoverable in pi-Base as space [S1103](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S001103/).

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the table in the back of Steen and Seebach's book. You will find that Example 103 contains a completely regular space that is ccc but not separable: $\mathbb{N}^\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is a cardinal number larger than $2^{\aleph_0}$. The Tychonoff cube $[0,1]^\lambda$ provides a compact Hausdorff example.

Comment: Or the Cantor cube $\{0,1\}^\lambda$.

Comment: Looks like we're missing ccc: https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S001103/properties

Answer (score 7):

How about the book *Chain Conditions in Topology* by W. Comfort and S. Negrepontis, Cambridge University Press (1982)? There's a lot of stuff in here.

For the third bullet point you can try Bell's [A Normal First Countable ccc Nonseparable Space](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1979-074-01/S0002-9939-1979-0521889-0/S0002-9939-1979-0521889-0.pdf), or Tall's [The Countable Chain Condition Versus Separability](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0016660X74900105).

Answer (score 1):

A very nice example of a completely regular ccc non-separable space is the [Pixley-Roy hyperspace](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2014/02/16/pixley-roy-hyperspaces/) of the reals. While it's not metrizable (and it can't be, as you already know) it is as close as it gets to being metric. In fact, it's a Moore space.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a couple of chapters in books.

Lectures on Set Theoretic Topology
M. E. Rudin
Softcover ISBN:     978-0-8218-1673-8
Product Code:   CBMS/23
(available on Internet archive for 1 hour borrowing
https://archive.org/details/lecturesonsetthe0000rudi/mode/1up?view=theater)

In particular about ccc see:

Chapter III. Souslin Trees and Martin's Axiom

Also
Handbook of set-theoretic topology
Kenneth Kunen, Jerry E. Vaughan, 1984

(I think one could find info about ccc in various chapters, but in particular about cardinal invariants.)

Contents:\ R. Hodel, Cardinal functions. I (pp. 1–61); I. Juhasz, Cardinal functions. II (pp. 63–109); Eric K. van Douwen, The integers and topology (pp. 111–167); Scott W. Williams, Box products (pp. 169–200); Arnold W. Miller, Special subsets of the real line (pp. 201–233); S. Todorcevic, Trees and linearly ordered sets (pp. 235–293); Judy Roitman, Basic S and L (pp. 295–326); U. Abraham and S. Todorcevic, Martin's axiom and first-countable S- and L-spaces (pp. 327–346); Dennis K. Burke, Covering properties (pp. 347–422); Gary Gruenhage, Generalized metric spaces (pp. 423–501); Jan van Mill, An introduction to βω (pp. 503–567); Jerry E. Vaughan, Countably compact and sequentially compact spaces (pp. 569–602); R. M. Stephenson, Jr., Initially κ-compact and related spaces (pp. 603–632); Peter Nyikos, The theory of nonmetrizable manifolds (pp. 633–684); Franklin D. Tall, Normality versus collectionwise normality (pp. 685–732); William G. Fleissner, The normal Moore space conjecture and large cardinals (pp. 733–760); Mary Ellen Rudin, Dowker spaces (pp. 761–780); Teodor C. Przymusinski, Products of normal spaces (pp. 781–826); William Weiss, Versions of Martin's axiom (pp. 827–886); Kenneth Kunen, Random and Cohen reals (pp. 887–911); James E. Baumgartner, Applications of the proper forcing axiom (pp. 913–959); R. J. Gardner and W. F. Pfeffer, Borel measures (pp. 961–1043); S. Negrepontis [ Stelios Negrepontis], Banach spaces and topology (pp. 1045–1142); W. W. Comfort, Topological groups (pp. 1143–1263).